# How can a file descriptor be reclaimed and reused later?

Tags: linux, file-descriptors, system-calls

In context of C and C++, is the `close()` system call the only way for kernel to reclaim the fd and reuse it later when calling `open()` in the same process lifetime? What about multi-threaded programs?

Comment: I believe your question is better on http://stackoverflow.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ than here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch According to [our guidelines](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic), this question is on-topic: it's the kind of things a user/admin needs to know when using strace to troubleshoot a program they didn't write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read more carefully [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Your formulation is wrong: close is a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for Linux) by which the application tells the kernel to release a resource (not the other way round). You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the system calls executed by some command or process. See also [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/execve.7.html), [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)

And yes, [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (and [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), see [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)) are common to all the threads of a given [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). However, you might (rarely) create "threads" directly with the low-level [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall (that is in practice only used by *implementors* of thread libraries like *pthreads*), and in the unlikely case you are *not* using `CLONE_FILES`  things are different. But calling directly `clone` is a black magic art.

For a given process of pid 1234, on Linux, you can query the set of file descriptors (in [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) thru `/proc/1234/fd/`  and the memory mapping thru `/proc/1234/maps` (etc etc... there are many useful *pseudo* files and links in `/proc/1234`). From inside the process, you could use `/proc/self/fd/` - e.g. as argument to [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html)

Of course, file descriptors are much more a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) or Linux thing than a standard [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) one. For instance, [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) & [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) is defined in POSIX, not in C99.

So if you see a given number -e.g. 49- been returned by `open` several times it is because some other part of your program (perhaps inside some library, in another thread) have called `close`  with 49. The kernel is never "magically" closing file descriptors (except at process termination) without been asked. You might use `strace` or use your `gdb`  debugger with a breakpoint (probably a conditional one) on `close`

Comment: Thanks Basile, I think the issue I encountered is that I have seen thousands of fd reusing without seeing explicitly close() calling when fixing our own IPC related bugs, which makes me doubt if I missed any possible means which could lead to this situation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment above (and even your question was strangely formulated): how have you seen "fd reusing" - do you mean "file descriptors been reused"? And like you, I am not a native English speaker, but you might try to find  better words in your questions & comments

Comment: I think my question is as simple as the following: in a complex multi-threading code I'm trying to debug now, I have seen the same fd (say 49) coming from open(curr_dev, O_RDWR) a lot of times ( which means fd 49 has been reclaimed successfully by kernel before everytime I called open() ), but I did not see explicit close(fd) in the code flow. So just wondering if there is any other possible way for system to reclaim that fd 49 instead of using close(fd). Hope this time it makes it clear. Sorry for any misunderstood I have introduced in my question and previous comment.

Comment: No, `fd`  has not been reclaimed by the kernel, but some other part of your program (your code, or some library that you are using) has *explicitly* done a `close(y)`  with `y`  been 49

Comment: cool, then I think I would narrow my concentration onto finding which function or lib I have called have done the close(fd) for me. Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: @lordofire see also `ltrace -S` to help identify shared library functions that may call close()

Comment: @lordofire: If you're trying to debug a program to find out where a file descriptor (e.g., 49) gets closed (i.e., you have the source code, and you can edit it and recompile), you might want to look at the [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) system call.  `fstat(49, buf)` returns 0 (and fills in `buf`) if file descriptor 49 is open, and it returns −1 if it is closed.  So, if you suspect function `foo()` of calling `close(49)`, then you should call `fstat(49, buf)` before and after calling `foo()`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: IIRC, pthreads should share file descriptors. Indeed, some other (non-POSIX) thread libraries might have separate fd-s.

Comment: Thanks @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

There are also syscalls other than `close` that may result in a file descriptor being closed and reused: `dup2` and, on Linux, `dup3`.

You may want to check your trace logs for these as well.